# Identifying a curve

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Question: What is the curve described by

$$x=t^2+t+1, \, y=t^2-t+1$$

My method: Differentiating both $x$ and $y$ wrt $t$,

$$dx/dt=2t+1.$$
$$dy/dt=2t-1.$$
$$dx/dy=(2t+1)/(2t-1).$$
$$x-y=2t.$$
$$dx/dy=(x-y+1)/(x-y-1).$$

Cross multiplying, 
$$xdx-ydx-dx=xdy-ydy+dy.$$
Integrating,
$$x^2/2+y^2/2-xy-x-y=c.$$
I don't know how to identify this curve. It isn't a parabola, ellipse or hyperbola because the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ are the same. How do I identify the curve?

Comment: Please do learn, **and apply**,  the easy directions of the site to properly write mathematics here. What you wrote is very hard to understand.

Comment: Where can I learn them?

Comment: I don't know...once upon a time there was a link attached to the right side of all the pages in this site, now I don't know... Perhaps in Metaexchange.

Comment: I found the link, thanks anyway.

Comment: One can determine which type of conic section this curve defines by regarding the l.h.s. of the last display equation as a quadratic form in $(x, y)$ and computing its discriminant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Discriminant_of_a_quadratic_form .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Eliminate the parameter $t=(x-y)/2$  from $x=t^2+t+1$, then you will obtain immediately the equation:
$$x^2-2xy+y^2-2x-2y+4=0.$$
Let $X=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x-y)$ and $Y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y)$ (this is a $45^{\circ}$-rotation) then the equation becomes 
$$Y=\frac{X^2+2}{\sqrt{2}}.$$
What kind of curve is this?

Comment: Is it better to let $X=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x-y)$ and $Y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y)$ which represents rotation?

Comment: @velut luna Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer. Is it better now?

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, it should be a $\pi/4$ rotation.

Comment: @velut luna Of course... Thanks again.